# how to traverse a tree structure and change its data type

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, binary-tree, huffman-code

I am attempting to implement huffman coding in haskell and use the following two data structures:

```
data Htree = Leaf Char | Branch Htree Htree deriving Show
data Wtree = L Integer Char | B Integer Wtree Wtree deriving Show
```

where Wtree is created first based on the frequency/weight of each character. 
After Wtree is constructed, and we know the structure of the tree, i no longer need the weights of each leaf/branch so i want to convert Wtree into Htree but i have trouble tackling this problem.

```
createHtree :: Wtree -> Htree
createHtree(L _ char) = Leaf char
createHtree(B _ w1 w2) = Branch createHtree(w1) createHtree(w2)
```

This is a solution i attempted but it won't compile

The expected result is as i mention the conversion from Wtree into Htree which only requires the removal of the Integer part of Wtree.

Comment: And I don't think that last line is grouped correctly, even though the intention is clear: try `Branch (createHtree w1) (createHtree w2)`

Comment: wow i can't believe that worked, it compiled now. I feel dumbfounded

Comment: `Branch createHtree(w1) createHtree(w2)` is the same as `Branch createHtree w1 createHtree w2` which calls constructor `Branch` with four arguments (triggering the error). Recall function application in Haskell is `(f x)` not `f(x)`.

Comment: thank you for clarifying, i was not aware there were an big differences between the two but i'll make sure to remember it ! @chi

Comment: Indeed, these are quite different. For instance `f x y` calls function `f` with arguments `x` and `y`. It is equivalent to `(f x) y`. Instead, `f (x y)` will call function `f` with only one argument, the result of calling function `x` with argument `y`. So, one should be careful with parentheses.

Comment: Worth pointing out, too, that `createHtree (L _ char)` works not because the parentheses are required for a function call, but because `L _ char` is a pattern match against a single argument, rather than one matching three separate arguments.

Comment: Yes, *expressions* to the right of `=`, *patterns* to the left! On the RHS `(L w char)` constructs *a* value (from two values), on the LHS it deconstructs such a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make this task simpler for yourself by using only a single data type, and parameterizing it by the type of data you wish to store at each node:

```
data HTree a = Leaf a Char | Branch a (HTree a) (HTree a)
```

Then, your weighted tree is `HTree Integer`, while your unweighted tree is `HTree ()`, indicating that you wish to store no extra data in the tree. This way, Haskell can see clearly that your two types are closely related - with the code you posted in the question, they appear to be two totally unrelated types. If you additionally turn on one innocuous language extension, you can use this close relationship to avoid writing the conversion yourself at all!

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Data.Functor ((<$))

data HTree a = Leaf a Char
             | Branch a (HTree a) (HTree a)
             deriving Functor

stripLabels :: HTree a -> HTree ()
stripLabels = (() <$)
```

Observe that now `stripLabels` is so simple you don't really even need to define it: you could just inline it at use sites.